# How can I create a zip archive without a file extension using the "zip" command?

Tags: bash, command-line, zip

Normally, to zip a directory, I can do something like this:

```
zip -r archive.zip directory/
```

However, if I try to remove the extension from `archive.zip` like this:

```
zip -r archive directory/
```

It implicitly appends the `.zip` extension to the output. Is there a way to do this without creating a `.zip` and then renaming it?

I'm using this version of `zip` on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
```

Comment: I'm just curious, but why do you need it?

Comment: @jnovacho I have a Makefile which builds a Python zipapp (zip file with shebang that the Python interpreter knows how to open and run code from). The executable looks cleaner if I omit a file extension extension as would be done with other Unix executables.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `-A` (`--adjust-sfx`) option causes `zip` to treat the given archive name as-is:

```
zip -Ar archive directory/
```

This works even when `archive` isn’t created as a self-extracting archive.

Answer (score 16):

You can have it provide the zip output to stdout and then redirect it to a file:

```
zip -r - -- directory/ > archive
```

The first dash refers to stdout and the pair of dashes separates the initial arguments from the input list, for clarity.